# How to set more than one image in OpenGraph to one object?

Tags: facebook, object, action, facebook-opengraph

OpenGraph:
I have one object A on which I make two different action: B and C.
Object has the same url to both action, but I want to set up different icon (og:image).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes, of course its possible.while posting the action, pass the object_url with image parameter which you can get and put within og:image tag in object script.
for example if you use [php](/questions/tagged/php):

posting the action:

```
$facebook->api("me/app_namaspace:action_name","POST",array('object_name'=>"$object_url?pic=$image_url, 'access_token'=>$access_token));
```

let say object_name.php has objects meta tags:

```
//object_name.php
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# postappfg: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/app_namespace#">
<title></title> 
  <meta property="fb:app_id"     content="appid" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"       content="app_namespace:object_name" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"      content="title" />
  <meta property="og:image"      content="<?php echo $_GET['pic'];?>"/> 
   </head>
```

Comment: why ? which programming language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

if we follow the Open graph protocol, an Open Graph object is defined by one picture. But it exists a way to change the picture of an Open Graph object:

Define a default og:image for your object, because it's mandatory and when you post the activity you must add a "image[0][url]" property with the URL of the picture. The og:image picture will be overridden. Example:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/mywhiskyapp:buy?whisky=http://samples.ogp.me/306369449462168&access_token=[...]&method=post&image[0][url]=http://img.diytrade.com/cdimg/339590/1362083/0/1144228175/WHISKY.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Smita you forgot the cache. Once an object is registered the og:image is the once registered and not the new one. Of course if you use the Facebook debugger you will see a different picture, but it's because the Facebook debugger "rescrape" the object and reset data.